# Sub Domain Routes and Controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and I am wondering is there a way to do this?

How could I make my subdomain load a specific laravel route/controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing):

> The sub-domain may be specified using the `domain` key on the `group` attribute array:

And the way to do it is as follows:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```